# displaying out of choices in dropdown menu

Tags: python, tkinter

When i print "chunk" ,the output will show me "PY_VAR0" Where have i gone wrong?

```
chunk = IntVar(root)
chunk.set("4") # default value to show on the GUI
print chunk

#option for segment size
chunkOption = OptionMenu(root, chunk,"4", "16", "32", "64", "128", "265", "512" )
chunkOption.pack(side=Tkinter.TOP)
```

Comment: This is not about your problem. Just a little tip. You can use `"top"`(lower case, with quotes) instead of Tkinter.TOP

Answer (score 0):

To use the value in an `IntVar`, you must use the `get` method to get the value:

```
print chunk.get()
```